# Anchor element not working in html

Tags: html, anchor

I have to complete a project that I havent been working on for ages ;-)
Since then we changed from using firefox to chrome.

Now. I have a table and each table row has an own anchor that allows me to jump to a specific row. This code used to work, but it seems something has changed.

```
<a name="row-36"></a><tr onclick="document.location =  ....
```

I also  tried

```
<div id="row-36"></div><tr onclick="document.location =
```

but when I call that anchor from the link the page always jumps to the middle

```
http://server/index.php#row-36
```

Any Idea? Does chrome treat those anchors differently?

Comment: Do you have any static header or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither an `<a>` nor a `<div>` can be a sibling element of a `<tr>`.

If you want to link to a `<tr>`, then link to *it*. Give the `<tr>` an `id`.